# Gracenote API: Fetching Contributors

Tags: api, gracenote

I have an issue with contributors in gracenote:
Does someone know how much "date" and "place" fields types there might be ?
For now, i only saw something like TYPE="BIRTH". I suppose there might be something like "DEATH", i just want a confirmation please.

If someone knows about it, that would be great =).

Comment: Can you clarify what SDK/platform you are using so that the answer can be specific to your usage? (but yes, birth and death are the two supported types)

Comment: Thanks. Web api reference. In fact i didn't notice theses types because i'm using a special function to get "simple" arrays of data instead of xml objects. The problem is that i lose cell attributes, that's why i didn't notice the "TYPE=BIRTH" attribute at the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TYPE="BIRTH" and TYPE="DEATH" are supported for contributor PLACE and DATE tags.

We will update the documentation to make sure both options are documented.

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time of answering this question.